# My tires are louder than normal

Tags: tires, noise, mazda, mazda-3

That is the simplest way I can describe the problem. I changed into my summer tires and after that after I get past 40 kph the car starts to get very loud. Between 60 and 100 is a little quieter but not by much. Driving at 120 kph is *tolerable*.

It does not feel like I have unbalanced tires since the care is not shaking or jumping. I  had a complete brake job since and the did nothing to change the issue. My car just drives loud. Likely unrelated but my A/C also stopped putting out cold air.

I thought maybe that I had rotated my tires incorrectly but they are not uni directional from what I can tell. I was going to rotate them again but I feel like that might be a waste of time.

Only other thing worth mentioning is that when I am turning left at higher speeds the noise almost goes away. Conversely if I am turning right it gets louder.

What is the possible cause of the noise in my 2012 Mazda 3?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

If the noise gets louder when turning in a particular direction it sounds like a wheel bearing failing. Mechanics often test wheel bearings by steering one way & then the other... basically this puts more load on a particular bearing and helps identify which bearing is failing..
Your AC may just need a re-gas or its belt tightening etc but this will need investigating further.